# Elements of one column that don't have a certain value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, let's assume the following one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'person':['Sebastian','Sebastian','Sebastian', 'Maria', 'Maria', 'Maria', 'Achim','Achim','Achim'],'item':['house','garden','sink','sink','gold','house','stone','gold','wood']})
```

Now I want to get a list of all persons who don't own a certain item, for example gold. I've fould a way to implement it, but I think there is a better way. That is how I have done it:

```
allPersons=df['person'].unique()
personWithGold=df[df['item']=='gold']['person'].unique()
personWithoutGold=allPersons[~np.isin(allPersons,personWithGold)]
```

Any suggestions how to improve the code? I somehow feel that there is a pretty easy one-line solution.

Comment: Your code look good to me.

Comment: @QuangHoang What about some grouping by 'person' with assinging each person a boolean whether it has gold? Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but would slower than your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With grouping by persons and further filtering:

```
no_gold = df.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: (x['item'].ne('gold')).all())
persons_no_gold = no_gold[no_gold].index.values
```

---

```
array(['Sebastian'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `pd.get_dummies` and indexing

You can also use `pd.get_dummies` and some filtering to get what you need instead of using `pd.DataFrame.groupby`

```
import pandas as pd

forbidden_item = 'gold'
pivot = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('person')['item']).max(level=0)
result = pivot[pivot[forbidden_item]==0].index.tolist()
result
```

```
['Sebastian']
```

---

The pivot table looks like this, so you can use this to work with more complex logic.

```
print(pivot)
```

```
           garden  gold  house  sink  stone  wood
person                                           
Sebastian       1     0      1     1      0     0
Maria           0     1      1     1      0     0
Achim           0     1      0     0      1     1
```

Comment: FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby instead. df.median(level=1) should use df.groupby(level=1).median().

Comment: feel free to ignore that warning. its due to the max function, but shouldnt have any issues.

Comment: But the code won't work soon then?

Comment: You can just use `pivot = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('person')['item']).groupby(level=0).max()` instead of that statement if you dont want the warning. both have same behavior :)

Comment: Here is more detail on the [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69618445/4755954) as well, for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean-indexing + `.drop_duplicates()` here:

```py
who_has_gold = df.loc[df.item.eq('gold'), 'person'].drop_duplicates()

persons_without_gold = df.loc[~df['person'].isin(who_has_gold), 'person'].drop_duplicates()
print(persons_without_gold)
```

Prints:

```
0    Sebastian
Name: person, dtype: object
```